# SQL update syntax with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, syntax-error

I have this `update` statement:

```
UPDATE quotedetailextensionbase qd
SET qd.new_capvehicleid = (SELECT cv.new_capvehicleid
                           FROM vwCapidLookup cv
                           WHERE cv.new_capid = qd.new_capid 
                             AND cv.new_captype = qd.new_captype)
```

I get an error back but I'm not sure why

> Incorrect syntax near 'qd'

Comment: You can't alias a table name in `UPDATE`, which is why you get the error. The best way to do this would be one of the ways below using `UPDATE qd ... FROM quotedetailextensionbase qd JOIN ...`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it would be easier to achieve this result with an update-join statement:

```
UPDATE qd
SET    new_capvehicleid = cv.new_capvehicleid
FROM   quotedetailextensionbase qd
JOIN   (SELECT new_capvehicleid
        FROM   vwCapidLookup) cv ON cv.new_capid = qd.new_capid AND
                                    cv.new_captype = qd.new_captype
```

Comment: Need to get rid of the alias on the left-hand side of the assignment in `SET`. Otherwise, it's still going to report an error.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below SQL:

```
UPDATE quotedetailextensionbase
SET new_capvehicleid = 
(SELECT cv.new_capvehicleid
FROM vwCapidLookup cv
WHERE cv.new_capid = qd.new_capid AND
cv.new_captype = qd.new_captype)
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server lets you do joined updates:

```
UPDATE 
    qd
SET 
    new_capvehicleid = cv.new_capvehicleid
FROM
    quotedetailextensionbase qd
    join vwCapidLookup cv on
        cv.new_capid = qd.new_capid 
        AND cv.new_captype = qd.new_captype
;
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Need to get rid of the alias on the left-hand side of the assignment in `SET`. Otherwise, it's still going to report an error.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use MERGE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx. That is correct when you would update from another table.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of just providing a link to the `merge` statement, why don't you show an example of how it could be used in the OP's case?